# Unity, xml и float.Parse

Tags: c#, unity3d, xml

Понадобилось сделать проект на юнити, ни разу с этим раньше не работал. Нашёл гайд как сохранять информацию об объектах на сцене с помощью xml.

Запись в файл получилось реализовать, НО дробные числа записываются через точку. А мне чтобы выгрузить из файла нужно string перевести в float. Я это делаю через float.Parse и он выдаёт FormatException, тк работает только с запятыми.

Попробовал в файле сохранить один объект и заменить в записях точки на запятые, и он нормально загрузился.

У гайдодела же всё нормально работает.

Думаю, что проблему можно решить, создав метод заменяющий в строке точки на запятые, но может есть что-то получше?

Пример строки из xml:
`<instance pos_x="30.2357655" pos_y="0.06069392" pos_z="1.70273745" rot_x="-0.978091" rot_y="-0.978091" rot_z="-0.978091">cubesand(Clone)</instance>`

Сохраняю координаты и не только объектов таким образом:

```
private XElement GetElement(GameObject obj)
    {
        XAttribute pos_x = new XAttribute("pos_x", obj.transform.position.x);
        XAttribute pos_y = new XAttribute("pos_y", obj.transform.position.y);
        XAttribute pos_z = new XAttribute("pos_z", obj.transform.position.z);

        XAttribute rot_x = new XAttribute("rot_x", obj.transform.rotation.x);
        XAttribute rot_y = new XAttribute("rot_y", obj.transform.rotation.x);
        XAttribute rot_z = new XAttribute("rot_z", obj.transform.rotation.x);

        return new XElement("instance", obj.name, pos_x, pos_y, pos_z, rot_x, rot_y, rot_z);
    }

public void Saving()
    {
        XElement root = new XElement("root");
        foreach( GameObject obj in objects)
        {
            root.Add(GetElement(obj));
        }

        XDocument saveDoc = new XDocument(root);

        File.WriteAllText(path, saveDoc.ToString());

        //Debug.Log(path);
    }
```

Достаю из файла так:

```
private void GenerateScene(XElement root)
    {
        foreach (XElement instance in root.Elements("instance"))
        {
            Vector3 position = Vector3.zero;

            Vector3 rotation = Vector3.zero;



            position.x = float.Parse(instance.Attribute("pos_x").Value);
            position.y = float.Parse(instance.Attribute("pos_y").Value);
            position.z = float.Parse(instance.Attribute("pos_z").Value);

            rotation.x = float.Parse(instance.Attribute("rot_x").Value);
            rotation.y = float.Parse(instance.Attribute("rot_y").Value);
            rotation.z = float.Parse(instance.Attribute("rot_z").Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не мучайся с этим динозавром, он умер и никто по нему не скучает. Используй json, в unity есть удобный jsonutilit.

Comment: `(float)instance.Attribute("pos_x")` - можно использовать [Explicit Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute.op_explicit?view=net-5.0) - это избавит от проблем с культурой.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к совету про `JsonUtility` вместо XML.

Answer (score 3):

Сколько лишней информации....

> Я это делаю через float.Parse и он выдаёт FormatException, тк работает только с запятыми.

Ознакомся с понятием "культуры" и иными версиями метода float.Parse - там есть метод который принимает культуру и в нем ты можешь выбирать по какой культуре тебе необходимо парсить флоат -- соответственно сможешь и числа с точкой парсить.

Comment: Нельзя удалять и добавлять код в чужих постах. Если у вас есть предложение по доработке поста, лучше предложите его автору.

Comment: @aepot а какой профит с кода если вопрос касается только метода парс? Информационный мусор.

Comment: Даже если профита нет, это не ваш пост и не ваш код. Права на редактирование даются, чтобы красоту наводить и ошибки форматирования править, а не чтобы полностью переписывать посты. Ладно, если автор не против, а так можно и на конфликт нарваться и на Мете обсуждать потом неделю, кто прав и почему бан. Зачем рисковать?

Comment: А получив привилегию можно предлагать правки автору поста как до привилегии?

Comment: Здесь вопрос здравого смысла. Вот зададите вы вопрос, а я потом приду и перепишу его совершенно неожиданным способом. Какая ваша реакция? Допустим, вы новичок и не знаете про функцию отката правок. В общем, я мысль до вас донес, что с ней делать - решайте сами. :)